gnome builder cannot find .pc dependency
I'm building a little test app for training myself with gnome builder.
The problem I have is that pkg-config is not able to locate libnm.pc inside
the PKG_CONFIG_PATH: /app/lib/pkgconfig:/app/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig
this one is very strange as in my system /usr/share/pkgconfig contains 'libnm.pc'
I think I should place 'libnm.pc' somewhere inside the flatpak sandbox where gnome builder is building but don't know how to proceed
some suggestions?
Thank you.
